# Indefinite article before the multiplication product: ‘a ten of twos is a twenty' or '‘a ten of twos is twenty"

Tags: grammar, mathematics

For an article intended for linguists only, I have to *unidiomatically* translate oral multiplication tables from a South Asian language to reflect the original morphology, and while doing so a question arose over the presence of the indefinite article before the product:
[in idiomatic English this would be  "ten twos are twenty"]
Is it *a ten/decad of twos is a twenty* or *a ten/decad of twos is twenty*?
Note that this is not idiomatic and I am compelled to choose the form "a ten/decad of" to reflect the original morphology.

I know very well that the form "a ten of twos" is not idiomatic and not in popular use. It is forced so as to reflect the original linguistic structure.
So I strongly advise that responders NOT focus on that and that they only focus on the essence of the question which is:
Is the indefinite article before the product required?

Comment: Who says "a ten of twos"?

Comment: English-speaking schools have their own local jargons, so there is no standard way to talk about multiplication. You'll get a lot of local opinions here; as a translator, you'd better consider where this is going to be read.

Comment: Please reread the edited question. I have clarified that the sentence is deliberately unidiomatic to reflect the original structure to linguists. So the focus should shift to the indefinite article.

Comment: what is a decad of twos? I think you are missing something in your **literal** translation. Literal translation can be used to **show the structure** of the other language, but you do not seem to be doing that here.

Comment: We use dozens not decades.

Comment: As I keep saying this is a translation of the original language's content and the original would in idiomatic English be translated as "ten twos are twenty"

Comment: You seem to be asking how English language rules apply to something you state deliberately isn't following established English language usage.

Comment: Please distinguish between idiomaticity and grammatical correctness.

Comment: @KillingTime Agreed, I'm beginning to think the question cannot be answered because it asks about a form of words that just isn't used. All that can be said is that it is a literal translation that does not work in everyday English.

Comment: You have now cross posted to ELL, which is not allowed.  I am a translator and I can tell you this: You either provide a literal translation that can at least be read in English or give up. Here, a literal way to say it based on what you have given is this: two tens are twenty. No "the".

Comment: The correct answer is: if translating from a language with an article or similar marking, use the article; otherwise don't. Why are you considering introducing words that aren't in the original, if you're told not to? Math tables aren't idiomatic things that operate according to grammatical rules, they're things people are taught according to rigid formulae and then forget, like tables of weights and measures or lists of verb conjugations. Do what you like, nobody cares.

Comment: Since neither *a ten of twos is a twenty* nor *a ten of twos is twenty* makes sense, it really doesn’t matter which one you pick. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - neither.
In the UK we are taught either

> Ten times two is twenty
> or
> Ten twos are twenty.

The latter is usually the way we learn our tables.

> Once two is two
> two twos are four
> three twos are six
> and so on.

Comment: It may be worth noting that, [as Ngram Viewer shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ten+twos%2Cten+times+two&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3), American speakers generally avoid the "ten twos" version, whereas [in British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ten+twos%2Cten+times+two&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) the two are equally common.

Comment: And gods know what they do in S. Africa, Australia, New Zealand, Canada, and India. To say nothing of various parts of the U.S, where there are absolutely no national standards for education (that fact alone should explain a great deal about American culture to the rest of the world).

Comment: Please reread the edited question. I have clarified that the sentence is deliberately unidiomatic to reflect the original structure to linguists. So the focus should shift to the indefinite article.

Comment: **Two tens are twenty**. There would be no indefinite article, at all.

Comment: My mother, born 1920, said she was taught 'once two is two, twice two is four, thrice two is six, four times two is eight (etc)'